# Keycloak 6.0.1 - Getting Started - securing servlet app fails to load

Tags: keycloak, jboss-tools

Running new Keycloak 6.0.1 install.    Following "Getting Started" - using keycloak-quickstarts/app-profile-jee-vanilla  application.  Wildfly version is 16.0.0.Final.  Why am I unable to load the vanilla.war file?

This is the error after running:  mvn clean wildfly:deploy

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project keycloak-app-profile-jee-vanilla: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"vanilla.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The required mechanism 'BASIC' is not available in mechanisms [KEYCLOAK] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory.

[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The required mechanism 'BASIC' is not available in mechanisms [KEYCLOAK] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory.

[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The required mechanism 'BASIC' is not available in mechanisms [KEYCLOAK] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory."}}}}

Answer (score 0):

This question may be a possible duplicate of: [How To Resolve "The required mechanism 'BASIC' is not available in mechanisms [KEYCLOAK] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201078/how-to-resolve-the-required-mechanism-basic-is-not-available-in-mechanisms-k)

---

However, I'm assuming you're following the following documentation: [Getting Started Guide  - Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html).

If that's the case, following the Github *README* for the quickstart is much better. Here's the link: [keycloak-quickstarts](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/latest/app-profile-jee-vanilla/README.md#configure-client-adapter-subsystem)

The *README* is more tailored for this quickstart project. Also, the documentation on the official page for this particular quickstart project isn't well ordered and might easily throw you off the bench.